# Customized partitioner failed to carry local variable in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Please help me to write a customized partitioner function in python for spark.

I have a file telling the mapping between the entry data key and partition id, I first load it into a dict variable "data_to_partition_map" in main.py

then in Spark

```
sc.parallelize(input_lines).partitionBy(numPartitions=xx, partitionFunc=lambda x : data_to_partition_map[x])
```

When I run this code locally, it gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/weiyu/workspace/dice/process_platform_spark/process/roadCompile/main.py", line 111, in <module>
    .partitionBy(numPartitions=tile_partitioner.num_partitions, partitionFunc=lambda x: tile_tasks_in_partitions[x])
  File "/home/weiyu/app/odps-spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1785, in partitionBy
  File "/home/weiyu/app/odps-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1392, in __call__
  File "/home/weiyu/app/odps-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 289, in get_command_part
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

It seems Spark cannot serialize lambda object, does someone have any idea about this error and tell me how to fix it ? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u tried to use a function that simply return the dict item, and pass it as partiction function?

```
def return_key(x):
      return your_dict[x]
```

Pass it as partitionFunction.